# what C++ casting operator is equivalent to (MyStructType){1,2,3}?

Tags: c++, casting

Is there an C++ casting operator (or combination thereof) equivalent to the old-style cast below:

```
struct MyStruct {
   int i;
   int j;
   int k;
};

void do_something_with_mystruct( MyStruct ms ) {
   ...
};

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   do_something_with_mystruct( (MyStruct){1,2,3} );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct

```
(MyStruct) {1,2,3}
```

is not actually a cast!  It's an ISO C99 "compound literal".  There is no equivalent using any of the C++ `*_cast<>` operators, because C++ (even C++0x) does not include this construct.  Some compilers implement it as an extension to C++, but you still have to write it this way.  See for instance http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Compound-Literals.html.

Comment: C++0x includes the same functionality as `MyStruct{1,2,3}`, without the parens around the type. I believe you are allowed to arbitrarily add parens around such a type specifier, so yes, `(MyStruct) {1,2,3}` is valid C++0x.

Comment: It does?  I couldn't find it in my copy of the draft standard, do you happen to know where it's specified?

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent to the C style cast is:

```
reinterpret_cast<ToType>(fromType);
```

It does a blind conversion of the bit pattern. Unsafe in most cases, useful when you need it.

Comment: care to offer an example that compiles? Because I tried that and it generates a compiler error.

Comment: @m1tk4: probably because the `< >`'s were missing due to bad code formatting. I edited the answer

Comment: they weren't in my code - I tried it before posting the question.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  See my response.

Comment: @Zack, I know. I was trying to edit my response before I got slapped. Having two unrelated people have the same response at the same time also points to value the error in interpretation.